# Joomla 2.5 404 on inner pages

Tags: mod-rewrite, joomla

I just downloaded a remote copy of Joomla 2.5 site, and when working in localhost any of the internal links work.

Home page and administrator work ok but internal pages return *404 not found*

Local site runs PHP 5.3.21 on Apache 2.2 under Windows (server is linux), SEF and mod_rewrite is enabled and htaccess works on other local sites so I guess it should be working.

My *hosts* file has an entry for this domain and set up a virtual host so URLs are exactly the same in localhost and in the server. This is apache access log entry:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2014:15:39:34 +0200] "GET /opinion/europe-today HTTP/1.1" 404 1480

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `.htaccess` file was copied when you downloaded the site. This would be normal given that invisible files are often ignored in copies.

I would check that the `.htaccess` in your sites root directory is the same as the live site.

The best way to make a copy of a Joomla website, that includes the `.htaccess` file and all the database and configuration details is to use [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html) in conjunction with the [Kickstart package](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html). The free Core versions of [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/akeeba-backup/) and [Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/kickstart/) will do all that you need if it's a simple move.

Comment: I agree with cppl, a quick way to test his theory before going through all the work is to disable SEF URLs and Use URL rewriting in Joomla back-end global configuration.  If you can navigate your site properly then the missing .htaccess file is the culprit.